# How to find a term in an arithmetic progression given relationships among the terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

The title is bad, but I was unable to think of better one, I apologize for this. 
I have this system:
\begin{align*}
a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 & = 34\\
a_2 * a_5 & = 52
\end{align*}

I have to find the $20$th member of the progression ($a_{20}$). Also I know that the progression is growing e.g. $a_1 < a_2 < a_3 \ldots$ 
Any ideas how to solve this task?

I've used the formula $a_n = a_1 + (n-1)d$, but I get an unrealistic equation.

Comment: The most straightforward, unclever way to begin is to simply use the formula $a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$, then you will have two equations in the two unknowns $a_1$ and $d$.

Comment: I've done that, i'm getting quadratic equation which seems unrealistic, however in the exercise is said that the progression is growing, so I guess I must have quadraci equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a system of two equations.  First off, $a_2+a_5=17$ because $a_2+a_5=a_3+a_4$  So your system is $$a_2+a_5=17\\a_2\times a_5=52$$  Do you know how to solve that system?

Comment: I'm getting to quadratic equation but it look unrealistic because the discriminant = 160^2 - 4*(-9)*235

Comment: The quadratic I get is $x^2-17x+52=0$

Comment: I have mistake somewhere, i will fix it thank you.